# Load a pre-trained model from disk with Huggingface Transformers

Tags: huggingface-transformers

From the documentation [for from_pretrained](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/model.html#transformers.PreTrainedModel.from_pretrained), I understand I don't have to download the pretrained vectors every time, I can save them and load from disk with this syntax:

```
  - a path to a `directory` containing vocabulary files required by the tokenizer, for instance saved using the :func:`~transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.save_pretrained` method, e.g.: ``./my_model_directory/``.
  - (not applicable to all derived classes, deprecated) a path or url to a single saved vocabulary file if and only if the tokenizer only requires a single vocabulary file (e.g. Bert, XLNet), e.g.: ``./my_model_directory/vocab.txt``.
```

So, I went to the model hub:

- https://huggingface.co/models

I found the model I wanted:

- https://huggingface.co/bert-base-cased

I downloaded it from the link they provided to this repository:

> Pretrained model on English language using a masked language modeling
> (MLM) objective. It was introduced in this paper and first released in
> this repository. This model is case-sensitive: it makes a difference
> between english and English.

Stored it in:

```
  /my/local/models/cased_L-12_H-768_A-12/
```

Which contains:

```
 ./
 ../
 bert_config.json
 bert_model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001
 bert_model.ckpt.index
 bert_model.ckpt.meta
 vocab.txt
```

So, now I have the following:

```
  PATH = '/my/local/models/cased_L-12_H-768_A-12/'
  tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(PATH, local_files_only=True)
```

And I get this error:

```
>           raise EnvironmentError(msg)
E           OSError: Can't load config for '/my/local/models/cased_L-12_H-768_A-12/'. Make sure that:
E           
E           - '/my/local/models/cased_L-12_H-768_A-12/' is a correct model identifier listed on 'https://huggingface.co/models'
E           
E           - or '/my/local/models/cased_L-12_H-768_A-12/' is the correct path to a directory containing a config.json file
```

Similarly for when I link to the config.json directly:

```
  PATH = '/my/local/models/cased_L-12_H-768_A-12/bert_config.json'
  tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(PATH, local_files_only=True)

        if state_dict is None and not from_tf:
            try:
                state_dict = torch.load(resolved_archive_file, map_location="cpu")
            except Exception:
                raise OSError(
>                   "Unable to load weights from pytorch checkpoint file. "
                    "If you tried to load a PyTorch model from a TF 2.0 checkpoint, please set from_tf=True. "
                )
E               OSError: Unable to load weights from pytorch checkpoint file. If you tried to load a PyTorch model from a TF 2.0 checkpoint, please set from_tf=True.
```

What should I do differently to get huggingface to use my local pretrained model?

## Update to address the comments

```
YOURPATH = '/somewhere/on/disk/'

name = 'transfo-xl-wt103'
tokenizer = TransfoXLTokenizerFast(name)
model = TransfoXLModel.from_pretrained(name)
tokenizer.save_pretrained(YOURPATH)
model.save_pretrained(YOURPATH)

>>> Please note you will not be able to load the save vocabulary in Rust-based TransfoXLTokenizerFast as they don't share the same structure.
('/somewhere/on/disk/vocab.bin', '/somewhere/on/disk/special_tokens_map.json', '/somewhere/on/disk/added_tokens.json')
```

So all is saved, but then....

```
YOURPATH = '/somewhere/on/disk/'
TransfoXLTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('transfo-xl-wt103', cache_dir=YOURPATH, local_files_only=True)

    "Cannot find the requested files in the cached path and outgoing traffic has been"
ValueError: Cannot find the requested files in the cached path and outgoing traffic has been disabled. To enable model look-ups and downloads online, set 'local_files_only' to False.
```

Comment: Not sure where you got these files from. When I check the link, I can download the following files: `config.json`, `flax_model.msgpack`, `modelcard.json`, `pytorch_model.bin`, `tf_model.h5`, `vocab.txt`. Also, it is better to save the files via `tokenizer.save_pretrained('YOURPATH')` and `model.save_pretrained('YOURPATH')` instead of downloading it directly.

Comment: Thank you.  I have updated the question to reflect that I tried this and it did not seem to work.

Comment: Please use `TransfoXLTokenizerFast.from_pretrained(YOURPATH)`.

Comment: @Mittenchops did you ever solve this? I'm having similar difficulty loading a model from disk.

Comment: I had the same issue when I used a relative path (i.e.  ```./data/bert-large-uncased/```), but when I went to absolute path (i.e.  ```/opt/workspace/data/bert-large-uncased/```) it miraculously worked

Comment: For what its worth, I used to the pathlib to overcome this. I could load the model from the file its self, but when used in a class as part of a larger app in a docker container, I have to use the full path to instantiate everything.

Answer (score 29):

Where is the file located relative to your model folder? I believe it has to be a relative PATH rather than an absolute one. So if your file where you are writing the code is located in `'my/local/'`, then your code should be like so:

```
PATH = 'models/cased_L-12_H-768_A-12/'
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(PATH, local_files_only=True)
```

You just need to specify the folder where all the files are, and not the files directly. I think this is definitely a problem with the `PATH`. Try changing the style of "slashes": "/" vs "\", these are different in different operating systems. Also try using ".", like so `./models/cased_L-12_H-768_A-12/` etc.

Comment: Sorry, this actually was an absolute path, just mangled when I changed it for an example. I updated the question.

Answer (score 9):

I had this same need and just got this working with Tensorflow on my Linux box so figured I'd share.

My `requirements.txt` file for my code environment:

```
tensorflow==2.2.0
Keras==2.4.3
scikit-learn==0.23.1
scipy==1.4.1
numpy==1.18.1
opencv-python==4.5.1.48
seaborn==0.11.1
tensorflow-hub==0.12.0
nltk==3.6.2
tqdm==4.60.0
transformers==4.6.0
ipywidgets==7.6.3
```

I'm using Python 3.6.

I went to [this](https://huggingface.co/bert-base-uncased/tree/345fd30026bc3003828be943882dda32ab48b908) site here which shows the directory tree for the specific huggingface model I wanted. I happened to want the **uncased** model, but these steps should be similar for your cased version. Also note that my link is to a very specific commit of this model, just for the sake of reproducibility - there will very likely be a more up-to-date version by the time someone reads this.

I manually downloaded (or had to copy/paste into notepad++ because the download button took me to a raw version of the txt / json in some cases... odd...) the following files:

- `config.json`
- `tf_model.h5`
- `tokenizer_config.json`
- `tokenizer.json`
- `vocab.txt`

**NOTE:** Once again, all I'm using is Tensorflow, so I didn't download the Pytorch weights. If you're using Pytorch, you'll likely want to download those weights instead of the `tf_model.h5` file.

I then put those files in this directory on my Linux box:

```
/opt/word_embeddings/bert-base-uncased/
```

Probably a good idea to make sure there's at least read permissions on all of these files as well with a quick `ls -la` (my permissions on each file are `-rw-r--r--`). I also have execute permissions on the parent directory (the one listed above) so people can `cd` to this dir.

From there, I'm able to load the model like so:

tokenizer:

```py
# python
from transformers import BertTokenizer
# tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("/opt/word_embeddings/bert-base-uncased/")
```

layer/model weights:

```py
# python
from transformers import TFAutoModel
# bert = TFAutoModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
bert = TFAutoModel.from_pretrained("/opt/word_embeddings/bert-base-uncased/")
```

Answer (score 5):

This should be quite easy on Windows 10 using relative path. Assuming your pre-trained (pytorch based) transformer model is in 'model' folder in your current working directory, following code can load your model.

`from transformers import AutoModel`
`model = AutoModel.from_pretrained('.\model',local_files_only=True)`

Please note the 'dot' in '.\model'. Missing it will make the code unsuccessful.

Comment: This worked for me. Off course relative path works on any OS since long before I was born (and I'm really old), but +1 because the code works.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to **config file** and **vocab file**, you need to add **tf/torch model** (which has`.h5`/`.bin` extension) to your directory.

in your case, torch and tf models maybe located in these url:

torch model: https://cdn.huggingface.co/bert-base-cased-pytorch_model.bin

tf model: https://cdn.huggingface.co/bert-base-cased-tf_model.h5

you can also find all required files in `files and versions` section of your model: https://huggingface.co/bert-base-cased/tree/main

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short ans.

```
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('path/to/vocab.txt',local_files_only=True)
model = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained('/path/to/pytorch_model.bin',config='../config.json', local_files_only=True)
```

Usually `config.json` need not be supplied explicitly if it resides in the same dir.

Answer (score 0):

bert model folder containd  these files:

```
config.json
tf_model.h5
tokenizer_config.json
tokenizer.json
vocab.txt
```

instaed of these  if we require bert_config.json

```
 bert_model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001
 bert_model.ckpt.index
 bert_model.ckpt.meta
 vocab.txt
```

then how to do