# How to compute sentence level perplexity from hugging face language models?

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model, huggingface-evaluate

I have a large collection of documents each consisting of ~ 10 sentences. For each document, I wish to find the sentence that maximises perplexity, or equivalently the loss from a fine-tuned causal LM. I have decided to use Hugging Face and the `distilgpt2` model for this purpose. I have 2 problems when trying to do in an efficient (vectorized) fashion:

1. The tokenizer required padding to work in batch mode, but when computing the loss on padded `input_ids` those pad tokens are contributing to the loss. So the loss of a given sentence depends on the length of the longest sentence in the batch which is clearly wrong.
2. When I pass a batch of input IDs to the model and compute the loss, I get a scalar as it (mean?) pools across the batch. I instead need the loss per item, not the pooled one.

I made a version that operates on a sentence by sentence basis and while correct, it is extremely slow (I want to process ~ 25m sentences total). Any advice?

Minimal example below:

```
# Init
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("distilgpt2")
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("clm-gpu/checkpoint-138000")
segmenter = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

# That's the part I need to vectorise, surely within a document (bsize ~ 10)
# and ideally across documents (bsize as big as my GPU can handle)
def select_sentence(sentences):
    """We pick the sentence that maximizes perplexity"""
    max_loss, best_index = 0, 0
    for i, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
        encodings = tokenizer(sentence, return_tensors="pt")
        input_ids = encodings.input_ids
        loss = lm(input_ids, labels=input_ids).loss.item()
        if loss > max_loss:
            max_loss = loss
            best_index = i

    return sentences[best_index]

for document in documents:
    sentences = [sentence.text.strip() for sentence in segmenter(document).sents]
    best_sentence = select_sentence(sentences)
    write(best_sentence)
```

Comment: There's a better way, use `evaluate` =)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the goal is to compute perplexity and then select the sentences, there's a better way to do the perplexity computation without messing around with tokens/models.

Install https://huggingface.co/spaces/evaluate-metric/perplexity:

```
pip install -U evaluate
```

Then:

```
perplexity = evaluate.load("perplexity", module_type="metric")
input_texts = ["lorem ipsum", "Happy Birthday!", "Bienvenue"]

results = perplexity.compute(model_id='gpt2',
                             add_start_token=False,
                             predictions=input_texts)
print(list(results.keys()))
```

[out]:

```
>>>['perplexities', 'mean_perplexity']
print(round(results["mean_perplexity"], 2))
>>>646.75
print(round(results["perplexities"][0], 2))
>>>32.25
```

---

### Q: That's great but how do I use it for a custom model that can't be fetched with `model_id=...`?

A: For that lets look under the hood, https://huggingface.co/spaces/evaluate-metric/perplexity/blob/main/perplexity.py

This is how the code initialize the model:

```
class Perplexity(evaluate.Metric):
    def _info(self):
        return evaluate.MetricInfo(
            module_type="metric",
            description=_DESCRIPTION,
            citation=_CITATION,
            inputs_description=_KWARGS_DESCRIPTION,
            features=datasets.Features(
                {
                    "predictions": datasets.Value("string"),
                }
            ),
            reference_urls=["https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/perplexity"],
        )

    def _compute(
        self, predictions, model_id, batch_size: int = 16, add_start_token: bool = True, device=None, max_length=None
    ):
        ...
        model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_id)
        model = model.to(device)

        tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
        ...
```

#### Argh, there's no support for local models!

What if we do some simple changes to the code =)

See [Load a pre-trained model from disk with Huggingface Transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64001128/load-a-pre-trained-model-from-disk-with-huggingface-transformers)

```
class Perplexity(evaluate.Metric):
    def _info(self):
        return evaluate.MetricInfo(
            module_type="metric",
            description=_DESCRIPTION,
            citation=_CITATION,
            inputs_description=_KWARGS_DESCRIPTION,
            features=datasets.Features(
                {
                    "predictions": datasets.Value("string"),
                }
            ),
            reference_urls=["https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/perplexity"],
        )

    def _compute(
        self, predictions, model_id, batch_size: int = 16, add_start_token: bool = True, device=None, max_length=None, local_file_only: bool = False
    ):
        ...
        model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_id, local_files_only=local_file_only)
        model = model.to(device)

        tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id, local_files_only=local_file_only)
```

Technically, if you could load a local model that you can load with:

```
AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("clm-gpu/checkpoint-138000", local_file_only=True)
```

you can should be able the `model_id` as such after the code change:

```
perplexity.compute(model_id="clm-gpu/checkpoint-138000",
                             add_start_token=False,
                             predictions=input_texts, 
                             local_file_only=True)
```

Opened a pull-request: https://huggingface.co/spaces/evaluate-metric/perplexity/discussions/4

Comment: This looks great, but how would I use my fine-tuned model instead of the vanilla gpt-2 one? model_id seems to expect something from hf registry.

Comment: I think I managed to hack it by manually saving the gpt2 tokenizer and moving all its files into the model checkpoint (fortunately no name conflicts). I can then pass the path containing everything to model_id and get some reasonable result. Marking this answer as correct

Comment: See updated answer. Also created a pull request for your feature, it's sensible that we should be able to load local models too =)

Comment: BTW, good hack (for the time being)!

Comment: Late to the party, but `local_files_only` should not be necessary. That flag is intended for offline mode. If the model cannot be found on the hub it will also look for the model locally.