# Pass a whole dataset contains multiple files to HuggingFace function in Palantir

Tags: python, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I am using the pre-trained model from HuggingFace ([dslim/bert-base-NER](https://huggingface.co/dslim/bert-base-NER/tree/main)). Normally when working locally or in a Colab notebook, we can use the code below to load the model:

```py
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("dslim/bert-base-NER")
model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("dslim/bert-base-NER")
```

This code will connect with the HuggingFace server to load the model directly. But on Palantir, we cannot do much unless configuring the security.

The workaround approach here is to download all the files and upload them to a dataset. We can pass a folder that contains these files to the HuggingFace function (check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64007213/9500955)) like below:

```py
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('./local_model_directory/')
model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained('./local_model_directory/')
```

For a model that has only a `pickle` file, we can easily read that file via a dataset called `classifier`:

```py
@transform(
    file_input=Input("/Users/model/classifier")
) 
def load_model(file_input):
    with file_input.filesystem().open("classifier.pkl", "rb") as f:
        model = pickle.load(f)
    return model
```

My question is: How can we open a dataset and pass a whole directory to this function on the Palantir code repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

`palantir_models` now publishes the below code under `palantir_models.transforms.copy_model_to_driver` that can be used in place of `copy_to_temp_directory`.

```py
from palantir_models.transforms import ModelOutput, copy_model_to_driver

@transform(
    file_input=Input("/Users/model/hugging_face_files"),
    model_output=ModelOutput("/Users/model/model_asset")
) 
def load_model(file_input, model_output):
    temp_dir = copy_to_temp_directory(file_input.filesystem())
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(temp_dir)
    model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(temp_dir)

    # Wrap files in a model adapter
    foundry_model = HuggingFaceModelAdapter(tokenizer, model)
    model_output.publish(model_adapter=foundry_model)
```

**Original answer:**

You can copy the files into a TemporaryDirectory with the below util `copy_to_temp_directory`. I've also provided an example usage.

```py
@transform(
    file_input=Input("/Users/model/hugging_face_files"),
    model_output=ModelOutput("/Users/model/model_asset")
) 
def load_model(file_input, model_output):
    temp_dir = copy_to_temp_directory(file_input.filesystem())
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(temp_dir)
    model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(temp_dir)
    
    # Wrap files in a model adapter
    foundry_model = HuggingFaceModelAdapter(tokenizer, model)
    model_output.publish(model_adapter=foundry_model)


def copy_to_temp_directory(foundry_filesystem):
    import shutil
    import tempfile
    import os

    temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    for raw_file in foundry_filesystem.ls():
        output_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, raw_file.path)
        with foundry_filesystem.open(raw_file.path, "rb") as remote:
            with open(output_path, "wb") as local:
                shutil.copyfileobj(remote, local)

    return temp_dir
```

If your hugging face model large, you may need to specify a larger spark profile like `DRIVER_MEMORY_MEDIUM` or `DRIVER_MEMORY_LARGE` to ensure the spark driver has enough memory for the model files to load correctly.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: In the `copy_to_temp_directory()` function, it should be `with foundry_filesystem.open` instead of `filesystem.open`, right?

Comment: Yes, that’s right. I updated the code snippet