# Loading downloaded LLM to my code error, probably caused by path error

Tags: tensorflow

I was trying to load a downloaded LLM to my code, but I went into a problem. When I try to use `AutoModel` to load the model:

```
from transformers import AutoModel
model_dir = AutoModel.from_pretrained("~/.cache/modelscope/hub/qwen/Qwen-7B")
```

I get an error:

```
OSError: Can't load the configuration of '~/.cache/modelscope/hub/qwen/Qwen-7B'.
If you were trying to load it from 'https://huggingface.co/models',
make sure you don't have a local directory with the same name.
Otherwise, make sure '~/.cache/modelscope/hub/qwen/Qwen-7B' is
the correct path to a directory containing a config.json file
```

However you may clearly find that the directory `~/.cache/modelscope/hub/qwen/Qwen-7B` is the right directory

```
(armlm) root@Gu-Fangtian:~/.cache/modelscope/hub/qwen/Qwen-7B# ls -a
.           cache_autogptq_cuda_256.cpp        model-00001-of-00008.safetensors  model-00008-of-00008.safetensors
..          cache_autogptq_cuda_kernel_256.cu  model-00002-of-00008.safetensors  model.safetensors.index.json
.mdl        config.json                        model-00003-of-00008.safetensors  modeling_qwen.py
.msc        configuration.json                 model-00004-of-00008.safetensors  qwen.tiktoken
LICENSE.md  configuration_qwen.py              model-00005-of-00008.safetensors  qwen_generation_utils.py
NOTICE.md   cpp_kernels.py                     model-00006-of-00008.safetensors  tokenization_qwen.py
README.md   generation_config.json             model-00007-of-00008.safetensors  tokenizer_config.json
```

I have already search the web, and I found this post `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64001128/load-a-pre-trained-model-from-disk-with-huggingface-transformers`, but it didn't solve my problem. I guess it was caused by the absolute path `~/.cache/modelscope/hub/qwen/Qwen-7B`.

Could you tell me how to solve the problem, or where to find the solution? Thanks.